# Appbar widgets not refreshing instantly on calling setState() Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-test

The `AppBar` of my app has the cart widget which uses a badge for showing the number of items in the cart.
When I place the exact same cart in my body of the Scaffold, it updates the state instantly on adding or removing items from the cart. But in my appbar, the cart widget's state doesn't get updated. It's very weird.

```
actions: <Widget>[
      Badge(
        badgeContent: Text('${selectedItems.length}',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
        position: BadgePosition.topRight(top: 0.0, right: 5.0),
        badgeColor: Colors.black,
        showBadge: selectedItems.length == 0 ? false : true,
        child: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.push(context,
              CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (context) => CartScreen())),
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
      )
    ],
```

As you can see, the `selectedItems.length` is the number of items in my cart.
Please help me out. Stuck here for a long time now...

Comment: we need code for the whole page to see where you update your variable.

Comment: Please add the relevant code so as to get an understanding of where the problem is exactly.